# Replace variable delimiter within list element with semicolon

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given list:

```
['1~A A1', '2~ B B1', '3~C C1', '4~D D1'] # Delimiter is not fixed
```

**Note**: I'm getting a dynamic list every time and there may be a different delimiter in the list elements every time.

Expected list:

```
['1;A A1','2;B B1','3;C C1','4;D D1']
```

Tried with the following code, which works fine for string type.

```
sniffer = csv.Sniffer()
dialect = sniffer.sniff(file)
deli = dialect.delimiter
file = file.replace(deli,';')
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: The delimiter cannot be *completely* unknown. For example, I don't assume it can be `A`. Define which characters can be possible delimiters.

Comment: The possible delimiters are `^ ; | ,`.

Comment: "The possible delimiters are `^ ; | ,`" So, `~` is _not_ a possible delimiter?

Comment: @tobias_k, Sorry! Forgot to mention that too.

Comment: You must define the task better. You can't let us *guess* what you could need.

Comment: @Tomalak, I am sorry that, will take care from next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the set of possible delimiters to be `^ ; | ,` and `~` (from comments), just use those in [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) and replace all with `;`.

```
>>> import re    
>>> l = ['1~A A1', '2~ B B1', '3~C C1', '4~D D1'] 
>>> [re.sub(r"[;,|^~]", ";", s) for s in l]
['1;A A1', '2; B B1', '3;C C1', '4;D D1']
```

Note that some of those have special meaning in regex, e.g. if you put `^` in the beginning, the `[...]` will be inverted. When in doubt, you can escape them as `\^` etc., but in this order is should be fine, too.

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex.

**Demo:**

```
import re
l = ['1~A A1', '2~ B B1', '3~C C1', '4~D D1'] 

for i, value in enumerate(l):
    l[i] = re.sub(r"[^A-Za-z0-9\s]", ";", value)
print(l)
```

**Output:**

```
['1;A A1', '2; B B1', '3;C C1', '4;D D1']
```

Comment: `[^A-Za-z0-9\s]` is very bold. (Also, regex always as raw strings! `r''[^A-Za-z0-9\s]"`)

Answer (score 0):

If the position of delimiter is fixed, then the worst solution may be the best:

```
>>> l = ['1~A A1', '2~ B B1', '3~C C1', '4~D D1']
>>> for index, value in enumerate(l):
    l[index] = l[index][0]+';' +l[index][2:]
```

Other wise, above solution by @Rakesh is good enough